# Adding Text to Jquery.HTML

Tags: jquery

I would like to know if it is possible to add text on html without using append. only using jquery html
i tried this but it doesnt work

```
$('#inventoryQuantity').html(var,'text-html');
```

Comment: .text("text"), also why the var thing..

Comment: sorry var = variable and no text just html

Comment: Note that `var` is a restricted keyword, so if you've attempted to name your variable that, then you'll likely have a syntax error to deal with

Comment: I see, well j08691's answer should be helpful then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just use the standard JavaScript concatenator `+`

```
$('#inventoryQuantity').html(var +'text-html');
```